# Add autocomplete for observable methods in angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, autocomplete, pipe, observable

I want to add pipe() to my observable, but I don't have autocomplete to this function.
this is my component:

```
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { interval, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private firstObsSubscription: Subscription;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    const customIntervalSubscription = Observable.create((observer) => {
      let count = 0;
      setInterval(() => {
        if (count === 5) {
          observer.complete();
        }
        if (count > 3) {
          observer.error(new Error('Count is greater than 3!'));
        }
        observer.next(count);
        count++;
      }, 1000);
    });

    this.firstObsSubscription = customIntervalSubscription.subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log(data);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        alert(error.message);
      },
      () => {
        console.log('completed!');
      }
    );
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.firstObsSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

I want to add pipe() for customIntervalSubscription observable, Does anyone know of any extension that does this?

Comment: You should be able to pipe your observable like this `customIntervalSubscription.pipe(...).subscribe()`.  Is this what you tried?

Comment: you should clear the intervall once you complete the observable, otherwise you will have a memory leak